# Where to put the SQL logic

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

I have an existing SQL Server database whose structure I can't really change, although I can add stored procedures or new tables if I want. I have to write a stand-alone program to access the DB, process the data and produce some reports. I've chosen C# and Visual Studio as we're pretty much an MS shop.

I've made a start at exploring using VS 2008 to create said program. I'm trying to decide where to put some of the SQL logic. My primary aims are to keep the development as simple as possible and to perform quickly.

Should I put the SQL logic into a stored procedure and simply call the stored procedure and have SQL Server do the grunt work and hand me the results? Or am I better off keeping the SQL query in my code, creating the corresponding command and executing it against the SQL Server?

I have a feeling the former might perform better, but I've then got to manage the stored procedure separately to the rest of my code base, don't I?

UPDATE: It's been pointed out the performance should be the same if it's the same SQL code in a C# program or a stored procedure. If this is the case, which is the easiest to maintain?

2009-10-02: I had to really think about which answer to select. At the time of writing, there were 8 answers, basically split 5-3 in favour of putting the SQL logic in the application. On the other hand, there were 11 up-votes, split 9-2 in favour of putting the SQL logic in stored procedures (along with a couple of warnings about going this way). So I'm torn. In the end I'm going with the up-votes. However, if I run into trouble I'm going to come back and change my selected answer :)

Comment: The performance may not be the same, as SQL Server caches ad-hoc SQL in a different way to stored procedure SQL. See my answer here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274411/do-stored-procedures-really-boost-performance-in-ms-sql-net/275010#275010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is heavy data manipulation, keep it on the db in stored procedures. If the queries might change some, the better place would be in the db too, otherwise a redeploy might be required for each change.

Comment: unless it takes 2 weeks to put database changes into production and 15 minutes for code changes

Answer (score 3):

Keeping the mainstay of the work in stored procedures has the advantage of flexibility - I find it easier to modify a procedure than implement a program change. Unfortunately flexibility is a double-edged sword; it's much easier to make an ill-advised change as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking a look at LINQ to Entities, which provides an Object Relational Mapping wrapper around any SQL statements (CRUD), abstracting away the logic needed to write to the database, and allowing you to write OO code instead of using SQLConnections and SQLCommands.

OO code (the save method does not exist but you get the gist of it):

```
// this adds a new car to the Car table in SQL, without using ANY SQL code
Car car = new Car();
Car.BrandName = "Audi";

Car.Save(); //save is called something else and is on the 
// datacontext the car is in, but for brevity sake..
```

SQL code as string in SqlCommand:

```
// open sql connection in your app and 
// create Command that inserts car
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
SQlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO CAR...");

// execute
```

Answer (score 2):

Versioning and maintaining stored procedures is a nightmare. If you don't hit serious performance issues (that you think will be resolved using stored procedures), I think it will be better to implement logic in your c# code (linq, subsonic or anything like that).

Comment: "Versioning and maintaining stored procedures is a nightmare" - why? I seem to manage it OK...

Comment: Maybe it's just my opinion, but currently we are dealing with a project that logic is implemented in stored procedures. To deal with versioning problems we keep versioning information in comments (duplicated of course). We also have special scripts for installing new stored procedures / modifying existing. To sum up, it's a mess and our team considers it to be a serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your point concerning performance variation between embedding your code in .NET source or within SQL Server stored procedures, you should actually see no difference between the two methods!

This is because the same execution plan will be generated by SQL server, provided the data access T-SQL within the two different sources is the same.

You can see this in action by running a SQL Server Profiler trace and comparing the execution plans that are generated by the two different T-SQL query sources.

In light of this and back to the main point of your question then, your choice of implementation should be determined by ease of development and your future extensibility requirements. As you appear to be the sole individual who shall be working on the project then go with what you prefer, which I suspect being to keep the code centralised i.e. within a visual studio Data Access Layer (DAL).

Stored Procedures can come into their own however when you have separate development functions within your organisation/team. For example, you may have database developers on your team who can create your data access code for you and do so independently of the application, freeing you to work on other code modules.

Answer (score 1):

Update deployment: If you need to update the procedure, you can update a stored procedure without your users eve knowing, without taking the server offline.  updating the C# means pushing out a new EXE to all your users!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Entity Spaces](http://www.entityspaces.net/Portal/Default.aspx). It's a code generation tool - but it'll do more.

There's a small amount of leg work to do in learning the tool, but once you're up and running you'll never look back. Saves hours of work. (I don't work for them BTW!)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I put the SQL logic into a stored procedure

Well that depends on what the “SQL logic” is, doesn't it? If it's purely database-related, a stored procedure might be most appropriate. If it's ‘business logic’, the rules that decide how your application operates, it definitely belongs in your application.

> which is the easiest to maintain?

Personally I find application-side code easier as modern languages like C# have much more expressive power than SQL. Doing any significant processing in T-SQL quickly becomes tedious and difficult to read.